# Emission node with alpha blend is colorless in png

Tags: materials, transparency

I have created the following flame material. You can see that the flame is red and emissive. Otherwise, the rest of the material is invisible, since I have "Blend Mode: Alpha Blend". Everything looks good in the eevee render. But when I save it to a png file, I see that the flame is no longer colored red (it is still visible, just not colored and clearly not emissive). I think it has something to do with the transparent background (If I put a solid black plane behind it, the PNG looks fine).

To test if the PNG file format is capable of holding those flames, but with color, I simply opened the png in krita, and changed the color of the flames then saved it back to PNG again.

Additional notes: I have chosen Color: RGBA, I have bloom enabled

**The view in Blender during a Render:**
[image: Blender Renders the flame fine]

**The way the PNG looks when opened in file explorer:**
[image: The PNG file as a strange tan color]

**My Node Setup for the flame material:**
[image: The node setup for the flame material]

**If I add a black plane behind it (making it no longer transparent), then the saved PNG looks like this:**
[image]

**Here I have simply changed the hues of the flames using krita, and saved it back to the same PNG format as before, still with a transparent background:**
[image]

Comment: Hello :). It's a problem with the PNG file format. Use EXR instead. There are already many posts on this site about this issue.

Comment: If you are curious to dive deeper into this hole, this post, or the posts that precede it, might help to elucidate the misconceptions around alpha. https://hg2dc.com/2020/08/26/question-25/